# Searchbar implementation at collectionView Header

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview

I am implementing a searchBar into a collectionView Header.

I am getting an exception here:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    let searchView: UICollectionReusableView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "SearchBarDispositivos", for: indexPath) 

    return searchView
}
```

The error message is: Editor Placeholder in source file.

Comment: this seems to be a simply Xcode error. delete the `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind`completely, clean the project, build the project. try adding `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` again.

Comment: @ocanal, I will try it

Comment: @ocanal, done, the error message dissapears, but launching the app I get an error: 2020-03-21 15:05:46.358118+0100 Jogua[15572:689310] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader with identifier SearchBarDispositivos - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard

Comment: That's a different error, but simply you must register that class before using it, in viewdidload, add this `collectionView.register(SearchBarDispositivos.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "SearchBarDispositivos")`

Comment: @ocanal, I will try another way to implement a searchbar. Thank you